# Perturbation of a Fredholm sections which preserves compactness of 0-set

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology, morse-theory, symplectic-topology

I am learning Morse-Bott-Floer theory and found the following cool paper

http://de.arxiv.org/abs/1310.5080

by P. Albers and D Hein. In order to prove a cup-length estimate on the number of critical points of a perturbation of a Morse-Bott function on a smooth finite dimensional manifold the paper makes use of a perturbation result. I would like to know in what generality the result holds and if anyone knows any references. The ideal result I can imagine is something along the following lines.

Suppose $\mathcal{M}:=s^{-1}(0_L)$ is the 0-set of a Fredholm section $s\in \Gamma (L\to M)$ where $M$ is an infinite dimensional Banach manifold together with an infinite dimensional Banach bundle $L\to M$. Suppose moreover that $\mathcal{M}\subset M$ is compact. Then there exists a small abstract perturbation $\tilde{s}\in \Gamma (L\to M)$ of $s$ such that $\tilde{s}$ is transverse to the 0-section $0_L\subset L$, is Fredholm with $index(s)=index(\tilde{s})$ **and** satisfies the condition that $\tilde{\mathcal{M}}:=\tilde{s}^{-1}(0_L)$ is compact.

Does anyone know which additional assumptions I have to make for the above result to hold, or if it holds in the stated form? Both references and ideas are welcome

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add some more tags to describe your question? You can have up to 5 tags, and there are tags corresponding to the arXiv classes (like sg.symplectic-geometry corresponding to the linked article).

Comment: You need not feel uncomfortable. In the stated generality the result is not obvious.  To obtain such a result you need to have some additional information about the Banach spaces  involved, and some additional information on the original section $s$ so that you can get a bit of compactness.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the tags, I have added some more now.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu I changed the question a little, since in fact the paper actually only uses the result in a specific application where additional assumptions are satisfied. However it is not clear to me exactly what makes it work in their paper. Do you have any suggestions as to which assumptions on $s$ and the Banach spaces involved I would have to make for the result to hold?

Comment: The tricky part is the compactness of the zero set. This requires some additional conditions on the original section and the nature of perturbation. The transversality is a consequence of Sard's theorem.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu Thanks for the help. I fully agree. The interesting bit is the compactness - which was also why I thought the result would be useful to have in abstract form, if it exists :)

Comment: @MadsR.Bisgaard  In concrete examples compactness is typically achieved  by first obtaining a priori estimates  (this is the tricky part)  and then invoking some  compact embedding results.  In the case of symplectic Floer theory or contact homology the compactness is the major headache.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu Ok, thanks a lot. I will have to take another look to see if I can figure the argument out :)